# Scenario for disabling the Charms Bar

Tags: wpf, windows-8, charms-bar

i need to disable the charmbar when i have  a wpf app running on fullscreen, there is a way to accomplish that? i need to disable it because is a touch screen app and i dont want user to switch to other applications
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you would need to work with the registry, specifically go to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell
```

Create a key called `EdgeUI`, then add a **DWORD** value named `DisableCharmsHint`, with the value of  **1**. You can either do the registry modification in-app or from outside the application, given that it might be a kiosk of some sorts.